# Changing page content in a switch statement using more than 1 variable in the switch parameter. Can that be done?

Tags: javascript

The situation I have is a drop down list and an image on a html page. I'm using javascript script. I'm using a switch statement. I've constructed my switch and case statements. So far I got an alert box for each case that displays a unique message in the browser when I make a selection in the drop down list. But I want the image on the page to change with each message. I tried using multiple variables in the switch parameter but that disables the alert boxes. Is there a way for me to use a single switch variable that can call the message boxes and the images?  Or is there a way to use multiple variables in the switch parameter? I've been researching the internet, even this forum for answers, but haven't found anything that matches my problem. I found some answers using if statements and AJax but that is outside of the scope of my homework and what we've learned so far. So basically my task is to use a switch construct to evaluate the selection and when a match is found, display the appropriate image and the alert box. Any suggestions.

Comment: I'm not going to read a paragraph that big, and others may not either. It's just *hard*.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm learning, so it's good to know what works and what doesn't. I will try to break up my paragraphs in smaller bits from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the source of the image for each case. Switch statements only accept one parameter.

HTML

```
<img src="image_path" id="myImage" />
```

JavaScript

```
var img = document.getElementById( "myImage" );
switch( value ) {
    case 0:
        alert( "message" );
        img.src = "new_path";
        break;
    case 1:
        alert( "message" );
        img.src = "new_path";
        break;
    default: break;
}
```

Comment: I saw something similar to your answer on Youtube but I wasn't sure if that would work. I'm going to try it. Thanks. It's also good to know from an expert that switch statements don't take multiple parameters. I was going nuts trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you need multiple variables in the switch expression. Rather, you need multiple statements in each branch of your switch. For example:

```
switch(selectedValue)
{
   case 'foo':
      alert('foo');
      imageElement.src = 'http://foo';
      break;
   case 'bar':
      alert('bar');
      imageElement.src = 'http://bar';
      break;
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be an absolute path, or it is absolute reference? All of the images are in the same folder.

Comment: It does not have to be an absolute URI, no; it can be a relative URI, in which case I *believe* it's interpreted relative to the URI of the HTML document. (For example, if your HTML document is at http://example.com/foo.html and your JavaScript is http://example.com/scripts/foo.js, then you can set `imageElement.src = 'images/foo.jpg'`, and I *believe* that it will resolve to http://example.com/images/foo.jpg. But, try it.)

Comment: I tried your suggestion using the relative path and it stopped my alert message from displaying. It gave me a default. I also tried using the img.src = "new_path" and got the same default. I used sunPic="document.getElementById("pic").selectedIndex; as the var name. I used sunPic in the parameters of the function and the switch as well as in the case statement. ie sunPic = "0" and so on. Any more suggestion?

Comment: @swydell: Sorry, but without seeing your source-code, I can't really guess at what the problem might be. I don't understand what it is that you're saying you've tried.